# Using System.IO namespace for FTP operations

Tags: vb.net, ftp, io

I have a few syncing routines that I'd like to use for FTP uploads. However they all use the functions in the IO namespace, and I was wondering whether I could use it to access distant files stored on an FTP server.

Maybe should I mount the distant server as a network drive? Is there a way to do this programatically?

Thanks,
CFP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTP functions in .NET are under the System.Net namespace.  You want the FtpWebRequest object.

See this article for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx